# Undefined is not an object(Evaluating _this3.props.navigation.navigate)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**user.js**

```
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => 
         this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsName') } >
     <Text>Name</Text>
   </TouchableHighlight>
```

**App.js**

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
  import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
  import LoggedOut from './src/screens/LoggedOut';
  import EnterMobile from './src/screens/EnterMobile';
  import EnterOtp from './src/screens/EnterOtp';
  import SplashScreen from './src/screens/SplashScreen';
  import EventsCalendar from './src/screens/EventsCalendar';
  import LocateMe from './src/screens/LocateMe';                    import 
   SettingsName from './src/screens/SettingsName';
  import SettingsProfilePicture from './src/screens/SettingsProfilePicture';
  import SettingsParking from './src/screens/SettingsParking';

 const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
   SplashScreen: {
   screen: SplashScreen
  },
 EnterMobile: {
   screen: EnterMobile
 },
 EnterOtp: {
  screen: EnterOtp
 },
  LocateMe: {
   screen: LocateMe
  },
 UserData: {
   screen: UserData
 },
 SettingsLanguage: {
  screen: SettingsLanguage
 },
 SettingsService: {
   screen: SettingsService
 },
 SettingsHoliday: {
   screen: SettingsHoliday
 }
 },
{
 navigationOptions: {
   header: null
 }
});

export default AppNavigator;
```

The navigation is given in a child component, could this be causing different behavior?
Using `stacknavigator`, when I click on the button I get the following error

> "Undefined is not an object (Evaluating this3.props.navigation.navigate)".

Comment: Change your TouchableHighlight to this, and see what you'll get in return: 
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log(this.props) } >

Comment: @kivul   `initDate: Tue Nov 27 2018 09:39:44 GMT-0500 (EST),
  scrollToFirst: false,
  size: 30,
 formatHeader: 'DD MMMM YYYY' ` This is the console output  .

Comment: @kivul one more  `onPress: undefined,`

Comment: can you post your entire App.js code? are you setting your constructor correctly?

Comment: @kivul  Updated the question.

Comment: `user.js` needs to be a screen inside the `stacknavigator`. if not you need to pass `navigation` props manually

Comment: on your user.js, are you initializing your constructor? like this: constructor(props) { super(props); }

Comment: @kivul  yes initializing like this and User.js not in stacknavigator.